# Separar resultados MYSQL por campo específico para disparo de email

Tags: php, mysql, for, foreach

Estou fazendo um sistema de notificação de disponibilidade (Avise-me) mas estou com dificuldades na lógica para fazer a iteração no *LOOP* agrupando os resultados por "email" para disparo separadamente.

CONSULTA

```
SELECT * FROM TAB_SITE_NOTIFICA WHERE INFORMADO='N';
```

ARRAY

```
$emails_de_envio[] =  $row_notifica['DESCRICAO']."__". $row_notifica_venda['EAN']."__". $row_notifica_venda['EMAIL'];
```

LOOP

```
foreach ($emails_de_envio as $key => $value) {  
 
    $SliceEmail= explode('__', $emails_de_envio[$key]);
 
    echo$SliceEmail[0]." - ";
    echo$SliceEmail[1]." - ";
    echo$SliceEmail[2]."<br>";


}
```

IMPRIME

```
PRODUTO 1  - 7899655052303 -  email1@email.com.br
PRODUTO 2  - 7899658322236 -  email1@email.com.br
PRODUTO 3  - 7899658376512 -  email1@email.com.br
PRODUTO 4  - 7899658342289 -  email2@email.com.br
PRODUTO 5  - 7896042066189-   email2@email.com.br
```

PRECISO IMRPIMIR SEPARADO E DISPARAR PARA CADA EMAIL SEU RESULTADO

```
PRODUTO 1  - 7899655052303 -  email1@email.com.br
PRODUTO 2  - 7899658322236 -  email1@email.com.br
PRODUTO 3  - 7899658376512 -  email1@email.com.br
________________________________________________________

PRODUTO 4  - 7899658342289 -  email2@email.com.br
PRODUTO 5  - 7896042066189-   email2@email.com.br
```

DISPARO

```
$return = sendEmail( TO, SITE, 'EMAILS PARA DISPARAR' , HOST, '[' . SITE . '] ' . $subject, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta a seguinte forma, transforma o e-mail na chave do seu array para você agrupar os demais dados por essa chave:

```
$emails_de_envio[$row_notifica_venda['EMAIL']][] =  $row_notifica['DESCRICAO']."__".$row_notifica_venda['EAN'];
```

Agora vamos incrementar um pouco teu `foreach`:

```
$prod_envio

foreach($emails_de_envio as $key => $value){
   $destinatario = $key; //Destinatário;
   echo $destinatario.'<br>'; //Saída;
   foreach ($emails_de_envio[$key] as $produtos){
      $pro = explode('__',$produtos);
      $prod_envio.=$pro[0].'-'.$pro[1].'<br>'; //Concatena os resultados;
   }
   echo $prod_envio; //Saída
}
```

**RESULTADO**

```
email1@email.com.br
PRODUTO 1  - 7899655052303
PRODUTO 2  - 7899658322236
PRODUTO 3  - 7899658376512
________________________________________________________
email2@email.com.br
PRODUTO 4  - 7899658342289
PRODUTO 5  - 7896042066189
```